# MiniProfiler Doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcminiprofiler

I just created a new MVC 4 Basic project and added the package to the project and the needed code to the layout but nothing happened after first run.

This is the Layout:

```
@using StackExchange.Profiling;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I've added this code to the `global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{

    MiniProfiler.Start();

}
```

now this code appears in the HTML code:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" id="mini-profiler" src="/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=xwYPDDH1blvqmxgsBweNC++H7CFU3KGQ+zFcVlJPsXw=" data-version="xwYPDDH1blvqmxgsBweNC++H7CFU3KGQ+zFcVlJPsXw=" data-path="/mini-profiler-resources/" data-current-id="6da0f73c-fa89-447b-92b1-56dc532947f4" data-ids="6da0f73c-fa89-447b-92b1-56dc532947f4" data-position="left" data-trivial="false" data-children="false" data-max-traces="15" data-controls="false" data-authorized="true" data-toggle-shortcut="Alt+P" data-start-hidden="false"></script>
```

but the `/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=xwYPDDH1blvqmxgsBweNC++H7CFU3KGQ+zFcVlJPsXw=` url returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to spaceman the problem solved!
the problem was from the 404 error solved by adding this code to `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Answer (score 3):

have you added the initialise code to the global.asax file?

you need to hook into the application_beginrequest and application_endrequest methods also.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/516627/MiniProfilerplus-plusInstallationplusandplusSetup

Comment: what's `application_endrequest`? I only added the `application_beginrequest` to `global.asax.cs`

Comment: i think you need to hook into endrequest also. it captures all data between the start and end of the request and then displays it. if you don't stop it then it never displays

Comment: its a method you can find in global.asax. if its not there then add it... 

private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){}

Comment: I did but nothing happened!

Comment: inside that method write MiniProfiler.Stop()

Comment: :D haha was just checking